Hydrostatic equilibrium and fluid velocity
If we consider a fluid with velocity $\vec{u}_0 = u_0 \hat{x} + v_0 \hat{z}$ which is now in hydrostatic equilibrium.
I know that the force associated to the gravity and force associated with the the pressure in $\hat{z}$ direction (vertically) must be the same but in the opposite direction. Thus, $v_0 \hat{z} = 0$.
What about the velocity in the $\hat{x}$ direction?
Wikipedia says that "In fluid mechanics, hydrostatic equilibrium (hydrostatic balance, hydrostasy) is the condition of a fluid or plastic solid at rest".
I'm not sure to understand why would the velocity in the $\hat{x}$ direction be zero.

Equilibrium only means that net external force $\sum \vec{F}_{ext} = 0$ on the system. This means that the velocity $\vec{v}$ does not change with time, because there is no acceleration. This does not mean that $\vec{v} = 0$ though. So your statement that $v_0=0$ based only on force balance in the $\hat{z}$ direction is wrong.
See steady flow.
Edit: You should revisit some good mechanics texts and revise Newton's laws. $$\vec{F} = m\vec{a}, \: \vec{a} = \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$
$$\vec{F} = 0 \Rightarrow \vec{a} = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = 0 \Rightarrow \vec{v} = const$$ (constant in time). This is Newton's first law. If gravitational force and pressure gradient are your only forces, your velocity cannot change in force equilibrium ($f_g + f_p = \rho\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = 0$). That's why I said $v_0=0$ based only on force balance is wrong. It should be $v_0=const$. If you have initial conditions/ boundary conditions, then that's different.
In reality, we have drag forces which are usually $F_d \propto v^n (n>0)$, so your net force changes over time, which kills your velocity. Consider a tank of water moving up at $v_0  = const\neq 0$. Would you say that the water is not in equilibrium (i.e. $\vec{F}_{ext} \neq 0$ so $\vec{a} \neq 0$) because the tank is moving? Do you see the mathematical inconsistency here? You only calculate equilibrium based on forces and forces don't change between constant velocity frames because they are inertial frames (1), (2).
If you get this, you'll see that $u_0, v_0 = const$ in your original question.

Yet, hydrostatic equilibrium occurs when external forces, such as gravity, are balanced by a pressure-gradient force. Which means that $$v_0 \hat{z} = 0$$, otherwise the fluid will be able to move upward. Wikipedia

Your fluid maintains its initial velocity, because there is no acceleration to change the velocity. If it wasn't zero before, it won't be zero after. Refer to the derivation and "Applications" section (last line) of the Wikipedia you linked. See the derivation here

The website you linked says "In hydrostatic equilibrium, $f_g + f_p = 0$". If there is no other force, if the vertically velocity is not zero then another force should be there and we are not in hydrostatic equilibrium. I can't imagine a volume of fluid moving upward at constant velocity and having the same dimension without another force (Maybe in the vacuum). I'm quite sure in this situation we are not in hydrostatic equilibrium, eventually the gravity or the viscosity will be greater than the pressure.

"If there is no other force, if the vertically velocity is not zero then another force should be there" - so how do you explain $v_0=const\neq0$ scenarios? You seem to have a problem with non-zero constant velocity and zero force? See my answer

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you are mixing between equilibrium and hydrostatic equilibrium. I think by definition hydrostatic equilibrium means the fluid at rest. I keep looking for answer and I found multiple links ( https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/hydrostatic-equilibrium-and-navier-stokes-equations.917651/). For what is worth even chatGPT tell me that. I'm confuse.

If you can find a post somewhere that explicitly states velocity has to be 0 for hydrostatic equilibrium, point that out. Otherwise, I would suggest you prove/ disprove this for yourself. Invariance under inertial frames should mean fluid equilibrium is the same for any inertial frame, whether $v=0$ or $v\neq0$
